# How to catch logs sent to a udp socket and save it in rotational files on a linux host

Tags: linux, logging, udp

is there a standard way to catch logs sent to a udp socket and save it in rotational files on a linux machine ?
The background is that i have an application that send it's logs to a udp socket.
I want to catch those logs and save them in rotated files (oldest files automatically compressed, very oldest files automatically removed)

Thanks in advance for your hints.

Comment: `syslog` supports UDP, combine with `logrotate`.

Comment: Google ELK setup from digital ocean. Will be great if you wanna make info graphs and ensure you dont lose logs if the logging server goes down.